# Convert a value into another value

Tags: excel, parse-platform

I have an Excel spreadsheet that I want to import into a parse database. The values are not quite the same as the ones that I want to import it into. For example?

.csv file value = SRH
parse file = St Richard's Hospital

Also there needs to be an extra column added to denote that this is in the South East and in GB.

Is there a way of doing this?

Comment: I guess it is posible.

Comment: [Why is 'Can someone help me?' not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Comment: I'm looking for an automated way of doing this as there are a around 3000 records to convert

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. Your only option would surely be to have a list of CSV vs Parse values. 
Then do a lookup between the two, or a Case statement. Is that what you are after?

Comment: Possibly. I'm looking to first convert the values in an excel spreadsheet and then send them to my programmer to upload them to parse.